# AlarmManager when the phone is turned off - ANDROID

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I'm doing an alarm System but i've a problem when the phone is turned off.. The alarm doesn't work..

I'm setting de alarm as follows:

```
    public void doIntents(Context context, long milis, Tratam trat){
    cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Service.ALARM_SERVICE);

    cal.setTimeInMillis(milis);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);


    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, trat.getId(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,milis ,pendingIntent);

}
```

The Alarm works Ok when the phone is turned on..

What can I do?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you expect it to do? Turn the phone on or trigger the alarm as soon as the phone is turned back on?

Comment: I want the alarm rings even if the phone is turned off.

Comment: that would not be possible, its linux and it behaves just like your linux desktop in this matter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yea, the problem is your app isn't running when the phone restarts. You'll need to register a BroadcastReceiver that can receive the BOOT_COMPLETED message so it receives a message when the phone reboots. Then in the BroadcastReceiver you can either reschedule those alarms or whatever. But I don't think there's anything you can do about making your alarm trigger when the phone is off..(e.g. making the phone turn on)

```
<receiver android:name="MyBootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="BootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Thank you, I know it.., but.. How Works the Android Alarm? Doesn't use AlarmManager?

Comment: Yea, you need to use AlarmManager.

Comment: Yes I'm using AlarmManager.. but.. is impossible that an alarm sounds when the phone's turned off?

Comment: @HéctorOrtiz as far as I understand, it is impossible to have it sound when the phone is off.

Comment: @HéctorOrtiz: Nothing on the device runs when the device is completely powered off, or when the device has had its battery pulled, or when the device has been smashed by a sledgehammer.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare;) in iOS for example, the alarm works even the device is powered off :(

Comment: then android is lame. Nokia 1100 was my first cellphone that I bought in 2003. Even that can trigger alarms in power off mode!!

Comment: @PC. Yea, an Android device can play music, stream videos, pinpoint your location within meters, send emails, take photos/videos etc. But the Nokia 1100 can trigger alarms even when powered off so..yeah much better than Android...

Comment: Even the newer Nokia phones such at the N8 and E7 have alarms that work while powered off.

Comment: Android too triggers their alarms when power is off, you know? Just set an alarm and try. The phone will automatically power on. Trouble is, how do I do it myself?

Answer (score 4):

Alarms are cleared when the phone turned off and rebooted, but you can start your alarm using BroadcastReceiver that can receive the BOOT_COMPLETED

```
In Manifest.xml:

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  <application ...>
 <receiver android:name="com.example.receiver.AlarmMonitorReceiver"
              android:enabled="true"
              android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Java:

```
public class AlarmMonitorReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
  public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent) { 
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
      AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); 
      Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(context, ExampleReceiver.class); 
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentAlarm, 0);
      Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
      time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
      time.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
      alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(),10000,pendingIntent);         
    }  

  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like the following:

```
private val ACTION_SET_POWEROFF_ALARM = "org.codeaurora.poweroffalarm.action.SET_ALARM"
private val ACTION_CANCEL_POWEROFF_ALARM = "org.codeaurora.poweroffalarm.action.CANCEL_ALARM"
private val POWER_OFF_ALARM_PACKAGE = "com.qualcomm.qti.poweroffalarm"
private val TIME = "time"

private fun setPowerOffAlarm(context: Context, timeInMillis: Long) {
    val intent = Intent(ACTION_SET_POWEROFF_ALARM)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND)
    intent.setPackage(POWER_OFF_ALARM_PACKAGE)
    val rightNow = Calendar.getInstance()

    rightNow.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    rightNow.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    intent.putExtra(TIME, rightNow.timeInMillis + timeInMillis)

    context.sendBroadcast(intent)
    Log.i { "PWR STATE: pwr off Alarm is set" }
}
```

This is copied from the Android source code of the Default Clock App located at: `DeskClock/src/com/android/deskclock/alarms/AlarmStateManager.java`

Search for this function in the source code and see how they do it similarly. We basically send a broadcast to the `com.qualcomm.qti.poweroffalarm` package which will then create a power off alarm as you would do in the DeskClock app.

If we look at the decompiled source code of the `com.qualcomm.qti.poweroffalarm` we see that the manifest states something like the following:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.qualcomm.qti.poweroffalarm.PowerOffAlarmDialog$ShutDownReceiver" android:permission="org.codeaurora.permission.POWER_OFF_ALARM">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="org.codeaurora.poweroffalarm.action.ALARM_POWER_OFF"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This means we also require this permission for the qcom package to accept the broadcasted intent. We therefore set it in our AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="org.codeaurora.permission.POWER_OFF_ALARM" />
```

And then also request it:

```
    private val PERMISSION_POWER_OFF_ALARM = "org.codeaurora.permission.POWER_OFF_ALARM"

private val CODE_FOR_ALARM_PERMISSION = 1

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, PERMISSION_POWER_OFF_ALARM)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            arrayOf(PERMISSION_POWER_OFF_ALARM), CODE_FOR_ALARM_PERMISSION);
    }
```

Finally we want to call the SetAlarm function. We specify the time in milliseconds from now until we want the alarm to ring. For example in two minutes:

```
 setPowerOffAlarm(context, 120000)
```